# How to set YII2 Multiple DB Configurable?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

how to set database configurable in active record ?

This my file :
*app\models\multi_db\Devices;*

```
<?php
namespace app\models\multi_db;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Devices extends ActiveRecord
{ 
     private static $dbConn;

     public function __construct($config=[])
     {
        switch ($config['server']) {
        case '2':
            self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbtwo;
            break;
        case '3':
            self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbthree;
            break;          
        default:
            self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbone;
            break;
        }
     }

     public static function getDb()
     {
        return self::$dbConn;
     }

     public function findDevice($id)
     {
        return self::findOne($id);
     }
}
```

This my code to get device :

```
$model = new Devices(['server' => 3]);
$device = $model->findDevice(1);
```

But this generate error:

> Undefined index: server

I think the constructor not set in `findDevice` method?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump`-ing `$config`, and commenting out the switch-case code? Maybe you are creating another instance somewhere else in your code? BTW, you probably also have to call the parent constructor at some point.

Comment: I don't get it, can you give me an example to dumping $config ?
Becase if i commented out switch-case, the static getDb() not set and generate error for schema in Yii2.
Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($config);` and then you could do something like `switch(1)` to avoid the not-set issue, without triggering the error.

Comment: hi, thanks for helping me, the soju answer is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `findOne()` will use your constructor without providing server config, that's why you get this error, you could simply try :

```
public function __construct($config=[])
{
    if (isset($config['server'])) switch ($config['server']) {
        case '2':
            self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbtwo;
            break;
        case '3':
            self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbthree;
            break;          
        default:
            self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbone;
            break;
    }
    // don't forget to call parent constructor
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

But I think the logic here is wrong, this should be set using a static method, e.g :

```
class Devices extends ActiveRecord
{

    private static $dbConn;

    public static function setServer($id)
    {
        switch ($id) {
            case '2':
                self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbtwo;
                break;
            case '3':
                self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbthree;
                break;          
            default:
                self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbone;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static function getDb()
    {
        if (self::$dbConn===null)
            self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbone;

        return self::$dbConn;
    }

}
```

Then :

```
// find device on dbone
$device = Devices::findOne(1);

// find device on dbtwo
Devices::setServer(2);
$device = Devices::findOne(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have some mistake,

If you use `findOne(id)` mean you are getting to retrieve the value from DB.
When you should create you `server` this way

```
$model = new Device();
$model->server = 3;
$model->save();
```

You  have a mistake also in switch (you select always the same db ..dbtwo ) a think you should assign different `db` (dbOne, dbTwo, dbthree)

```
class Devices extends ActiveRecord
{ 
 private static $dbConn;

 public function __construct($config=[])
 {
    switch ($config['server']) {
    case '2':
        self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbtwo;
        break;
    case '3':
        self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbthree;
        break;          
    default:
        self::$dbConn = \Yii::$app->dbone;
        break;
    }
 }

 public static function getDb()
 {
    return self::$dbConn;
 }

 public function findDevice($id)
 {
    return self::findOne($id);
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, that's my mistake for same db in switc statement.
I've tried your code but still get the error.
I've confused how to create 'server' config when using db statement, findOne and other.
Thanks

Comment: Still same error,

 PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Undefined index: server

Comment: But have you create the instance like suggest ?. How do you retrive the istance from db?.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me. the soju answer is work for me.